How to curate text based on pre-defined rules
How to curate text based on pre-defined rules using Java, following are some of the examples
How to remove everything after "To help support the channel"
About organic gardening, bees & beekeeping, blacksmithing, plant breeding, composting, natural farming, natural handicrafts, terra preta, biochar, compost tea, garden experiments, growing fungi & seed saving. To help support the channel: BTC Donation Address 14Tp6keFTi7YGXZdj1EfajwcZGTVQkkFfm

https://www.youtube.com/@starsports has the following content. I would like to keep the About section, but remove everything under Official Website
About

Look no further if sports is your forte, head no further if you want to watch your favorite sport!
Links

Official Website
whatsapp.com/channel/0029Va6mIWNIyPtZGmLTup1w

Twitter Link
twitter.com/StarSportsIndia

Facebook Link
facebook.com/starsportsindia

Instagram Link
instagram.com/starsportsindia


How to remove everything after "To help support the channel"
First, find the position of that string:
String text = "About organic gardening, bees & beekeeping, blacksmithing, plant breeding, composting, natural farming, natural handicrafts, terra preta, biochar, compost tea, garden experiments, growing fungi & seed saving. To help support the channel: BTC Donation Address 14...";
int pos = text.indexOf("To help support the channel");

As soon as you have the position you know where to cut the string. You can  get the front part like so:
String beginning = text.substring(0, pos);

There are caveats though. Check the value of pos to make sure the searched passage is found in text at all. And check whether that is the position you want to cut at.
String text = "About organic gardening, bees & beekeeping, blacksmithing, plant breeding, composting, natural farming, natural handicrafts, terra preta, biochar, compost tea, garden experiments, growing fungi & seed saving. To help support the channel: BTC Donation Address 14...";
String substring = "To help support the channel";
int pos = text.indexOf(substring);
String result = null;
if (pos >= 0) {
    beginning = text.substring(0, pos + substring.length());
}

Look at the documentation to see what methods String offers for modification:
https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html
Plus there are several ways to achieve the same. You may find alternative paths.
